# jQuery hover() - Visual Issue When Mouse Runs Over Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

Hey I'm very new to jQuery with little programming knowledge so please bear with me on this.

I created a script that will fade between two images on hover. The issue is that the fade effect continues if the cursor isn't hovering the image which means that if a user simply passes their cursor through the image whilst travelling to an alternative destination, they will see the full fade effect. Also if a user passes their cursor over the image multiple times, the fade effect will show multiple times.

Please see the image at the bottom of the page here:

http://ts564737-container.zoeysite.com/

Please see my jQuery below:

```
var imgelement = "#element"; /* Element containing the original image */
var hoverimageurl = "www.domain.com/newimageurl.png"; /* Image URL of the hover image */

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    /* Add CSS and a class to the original image to fix positioning and give it an identification */
    jQuery(imgelement + " img").addClass("originalimage").css("position", "relative");

    /* Prepend hover image to the element. Set the SRC to the hover image URL */
    jQuery(imgelement).prepend('<img class="hoverimage" style="position: absolute; width: 100% !important; height: 100% !important;" src="' + hoverimageurl + '">');

    /* Fade out original image and fade in hover image on hover */
    jQuery(imgelement).hover(function() {
        jQuery(imgelement + " .originalimage").fadeTo(1000, 0);
        jQuery(imgelement + " .hoverimage").fadeTo(1000, 1);
    }, function() {
        jQuery(imgelement + " .hoverimage").fadeTo(1000, 0);
        jQuery(imgelement + " .originalimage").fadeTo(1000, 1);
    });

});
```

Could anybody please advise what I need to do to avoid this from happening? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You need to use [stop(true)](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: You don't need a script for this. It can be done with only CSS.

Comment: @pol - I agree, but I'm looking to add some more complex effects after building this base script. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.stop( true)` to stop any currently-running animation on the matched elements.

`jQuery(imgelement + " .hoverimage").stop( true).fadeTo(1000, 0);`

Comment: you are welcome. jquery has lot of things just you need to dig deeper